# How to check the size of a file?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have a little php script that lists all the files inside a directory. I'd like it not to read all the files that are less than 10kb. What is the best way to do it ?

```
<?php
function scd($dir){$files=scandir($dir);sort($files);reset($files);return $files;}
$dir='images';
$files=scd($dir);
$counter = 0;
foreach($files as $file){
    if($file==='.'||$file==='..'){continue;}
         $output .='"'.$dir.'/'.$file.'", ';
}
echo $output;
?>
```

Comment: you can check filesize in foreach function and let that continue if condition match

Comment: Use the php function filesize() http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function scd($dir)
{
    $files = scandir($dir);
    sort($files);
    reset($files);

    return $files;
}

$dir = 'images';
$files = scd($dir);
$counter = 0;
foreach ($files as $file) {
    if ($file === '.' || $file === '..' || filesize($dir . '/' . $file) < 1024 * 10) {
        continue;
    }
    $output .= '"' . $dir . '/' . $file . '", ';
}
echo $output;
```

Google could have told you that..

Comment: https://www.google.be/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=thank+you